# Variable in the name of class

Tags: php, class, variables

I need to create a new object which class is named for example 'Statistics1' - the '1' I got in a variable, so I need something like this:

```
$table = new Statistics${$mode};
```

It doesn't work. For variable in variables I use:

```
$var = ${"text" . $second_var};
```

But this time it's not a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class name could be an variable [since PHP5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.changelog.php)

> Changed: It's now possible to reference the class using a variable (e.g., echo $classname::constant;). The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g., self, parent or static).

So sample code could looks like this.

```
class foo1
    {}

$one = 1;
$class_name = 'foo' . $one;
$bar = new $class_name;
var_dump($bar);
```

Comment: No doubt - it's a big simplification. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer reflection, because it's easier to catch exceptions:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Statistics'.$mode);
$table = $reflector->newInstance($arg1, $arg2);
```